# Define custom twig page template for specific multiple node pages by nid - page--custom.html.twig

Tags: 8, theming, hooks

I have a page from different content type and I want to define a custom twig page template to these pages by their nid.

Eg. I have pages like **node/2**, **node/4**, **node/20** and **node/40** from the different content type and I want to apply **`page--custom.html.twig`** template only these specific pages by checking their ID.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page describes everything about naming conventions, [twig template naming conventions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/twig-template-naming-conventions).

As described it is possible to do like this: `node--nodeid.html.twig`, 
e.g `node--2.html.twig`.

The smartest way will be to implement the `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()`, like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function THEMENAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    $nodes = [2, 4, 20, 40];
    if (in_array($node->id(), $nodes)) {
      $suggestions[] = 'page__custom';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a swich block in your situation.

Comment: `in_array` would be more readable

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter()`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_page_alter().
 */
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) {
    if ($node->id() == 2 || $node->id() == 4 || $node->id() == 20 || $node->id() == 40) {
      $suggestions[] = 'page__custom';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Razeem. its worked! also if I have an absolute path, like views path (news, publication etc.). How can I check these absolute paths and nid together in the previous code?

Comment: You can get the path of the node like `$node->url()` to get full path including http use something like`$node->url('canonical', ['absolute' => true])`